# A simple AJAX example - Silverstripe

Tags: silverstripe

Would anyone be able to post a simple example of working with AJAX requests in silverstripe? Couldn't find much documentation on this.

Let's say we create a page type 'AjaxPage' and have the controller output a form with a text box to enter your name and a submit button. I'd like to see the form processed and return a value e.g 'hello mike' so that i can output it in the AjaxPage layout file.

I just need to see the process/steps invovled.

Many thanks!

Comment: Googling "Silverstripe AJAX" brings up some promising results.

Comment: this link is close to a answer :)
http://ajax-silverstripe.mmkdigital.com/#/

Comment: I did find an example ceejay but it's from 2012, probably SS v2.4 and a lot has changed since then from what i've read..so I was looking for an up to date example

Cheers munomono, I hadn't come across that link, it looks excellent! - about to dive in and have a crack now :) thanks

Comment: There didn't change much from 2.4 to 3.x. Most important thing is http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-Director.html#_is_ajax `Director::is_ajax()` to check for ajax calls. This way you use the same controller action for both, normal and ajax calls.

Comment: seaching the new docs for "ajax" i get this page, which might be useful in this context: http://doc.silverstripe.org/en/developer_guides/templates/rendering_templates/

Comment: @munomono's comment seems like an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All credits go [to @thehacksaw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28151678/a-simple-ajax-example-silverstripe/42086028#comment44676140_28151678):

https://web.archive.org/web/20150805051807/http://ajax-silverstripe.mmkdigital.com/

Comment: Seems like a dead link.

Comment: Dead link, no longer a helpful answer